# Как с помощью `askopenfilename` или `askopenfile` вывести имя открытого файла?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как с помощью `askopenfilename` или `askopenfile` вывести имя открытого файла?

Comment: `askopenfilename()` возвращает имя выбранного файла. В чём вопрос? Как напечатать строку?

Answer (score 2):

Сделал так:

```
fileOpen = askopenfile(defaultextension=".txt",
filetypes=[("All types",".*")],
initialdir="D:/")
```

После:

```
if ( not fileOpen ):
   return

self.placeText.delete(1.0,END)
self.placeText.insert(END,fileOpen.read())

self.documentOpened = sub("\w+.*/","",fileOpen.name)

self.windowMain.title(self.titleMainWindow+" - "+self.documentOpened)
fileOpen.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Что может быть проще? Вот (*Python 3*):

```
import tkinter.filedialog

print(tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename())

file = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile("r")
print(file.name)
```

Comment: спасибо, но уже сделал. Долго не мог найти параметр `name`.